# Finding merge sort complexity algebraically

Tags: algorithm, computer-science

In one of my lecture slides I have been shown a way to prove the time complexity of merge sort algebraically. However, when I follow through this method I produce the wrong result. Here are some images to illustrate their method.

[image]

[image]

When I follow this algorithm, when I get to the end I have an extra 2^k in front of the f(1) which should yield an extra 2^k. Therefore we get 2^k + 2 * (2^k) * k which gives me n + 2 * n * log(n).

Can someone please explain where that extra 2^k goes?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right that the image omits this term, and it should be considered an error. It says:

(2) =  ⋅ 2 ⋅ 2

But it should say:

(2) = 2 +  ⋅ 2 ⋅ 2

...which after substitution becomes:

() =  + log<sub><sub>2</sub></sub> ⋅ 2 ⋅

However, the most significant term is the only one that determines the asymptotic complexity, and log<sub><sub>2</sub></sub> has greater significance than , so we still derive O(log).